# What is the purpose of `pure` in Applicative Functor

Tags: haskell, applicative, category-theory

> Meet the Applicative typeclass. It lies in the Control.Applicative module and it defines two methods, `pure and <*>`. It doesn't provide a default implementation for any of them, so we have to define them both if we want something to be an applicative functor.

I am trying to understand who is using `pure` function. I do use `(<*>)` function for which applicative functors are most useful for. But I am not sure who really uses `pure`.

I read something like `pure (+3) <*> Just 10` but it can be written as `Just (+3) <*> Just 10` too.

Above is just one confusion of too many I have. What is the true purpose of defining `pure` and when do I get to use it (or) who is already using it?

Comment: `pure` encapsulates a value into an arbitrary `Applicative` functor. Hence, `pure 0` can mean any of: `Just 0`, `[0]`, `\_ -> 0`, `(mempty, 0)`, etc. Also note that `return = pure`.

Comment: Perfect, I could see how `pure` can be used to get a kind of polymorphism. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few situations to use `pure`.

1. As freestyle's answer illustrated, when you don't know what specific `Applicative` is being used.
2. Also from freestyle, when its just more convenient to use `pure`.

In addition to just being simpler to write in some cases, it can make your code more robust. As I've develop software, my key data structures often evolve. Using `pure` instead of a specific constructor helps create spots of code that can remain unchanged during refactoring.

3. When the implementation of the specific `Applicative` is unavailable.

Sometimes a library will not export constructors for their data types. Instead they rely on functions to build valid instances of the types. Making that type a member of `Applicative` is one way to do this. The `IO` Monad (Applicative) is another example of a type for which a constructor just isn't available. Instead, we are forced to use `pure` (aka `return`).

Answer (score 19):

`<*> :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, this operator accepts a function in the applicative type, as well as a value in the applicative type. The first argument of this operator can not thus be simply a function, but it has to be residing within an applicative.

The `pure` function solves problems that might occur here (e.g wanting to apply a function that is not residing in the applicative). It accepts a function that is not currently residing in the applicative, and lifts it into the applicative.`pure :: a -> f a`

`(+3) :: Int -> Int`, and `Just 10 :: Maybe Int`, you can not thus evaluate `(+3) <*> Just 10` as the types do not work; the `(+3)` has to be promoted to a value in the `Maybe` applicative.

For `Maybe a`, the definition of `pure` is `pure = Just`, which is why you can write either `pure (+3)` or `Just (+3)`

--

I'll leave it to you to look into the `<$>` operator :-) Remember, every Applicative is a Functor.

Comment: "wanting to apply a function that is not residing in the applicative", in this case I would prefer using `fmap` because I know it is already a Functor isn't it ?

Comment: @SumanthKumarMora That's exactly right. `fmap` is more compact in that case.

Comment: @SumanthKumarMora yes, there may however be other cases where we simply wish to promote a function to reside in the Applicative. These are my teachers lecture notes for Applicatives, i hope they might be helpful :) http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/course/TDA342_Advanced_Functional_Programming/lecture4.html

Comment: @RobertK, Thanks a lot, I will have at look at those lecture notes.

Answer (score 6):

`pure` is like `mempty` for `Monoid`. `mempty` is neutral for `mappend`. `pure` is also neutral (in some sence) for `<*>`, it lifts some value to the functor without any effects or lifts with neutral effect.

This sentence can be formalized with four properties (copy/past from docs on `Applicative`):

```
pure id <*> v = v
pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w = u <*> (v <*> w)
pure f <*> pure x = pure (f x)
u <*> pure y = pure ($ y) <*> u
```

> What is the true purpose of defining pure and when do I get to use it (or) who is already using it?

Well, basically for writing more generalized code. For example:

```
when :: Applicative f => Bool -> f () -> f ()
when p s = if p then s else pure ()

sequenceA_ :: Applicative f => [f a] -> f ()
sequenceA_ = foldr (*>) (pure ())

traverse_ :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> [a] -> f ()
traverse_ f = foldr ((*>) . f) (pure ())
```

Also, sometime more simpler to use `pure` then implicitly wrap a value to a functor. For example, compare:

```
pure 3 ~ StateT (\s -> Identity (3, s))
```